# Simple FormData not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to test a simple FormData object but its not working at all. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8j80898h/

html code:

```
<form id="createForm" name="createForm" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Name1" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="button" id="submitIt" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitIt').click(function() {
        var fd =  new FormData($('#createForm')[0]);
        fd.append( 'name', $('input[name=name]').val());

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){                    
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Server is always getting null values for name and file

Comment: similar problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: how are you posting the value to server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: check the ajax request using the browser network tab(dveloper tools)

Comment: Yes its sending correct values... I think the issue is on server. Posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114269/dataform-posting-values-but-on-server-its-null

Answer (score 2):

FormData has a `get` method you should use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitIt').click(function() {
        var d = new FormData($('form')[0]);        
        alert(d.get('name'));
    });
});
```

read more in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get

Comment: only supported in Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

rather than making an `FormData` object you can access elements within an form like the code below shows :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitIt').click(function() {
    var d = $('form').toArray();        
    alert(d[0].name);
  });
});
```

Comment: then how u will post values and file?

Comment: ah the question had changed and i didnt see the ajax request part if you just do a standard submit without trying to handle it all then it will send up all the values that are set on the form including the file.