# DataForm posting values but on server its null

Tags: java, spring-mvc

using the DataForm object I found that its posting values correctly to server. Here is the screenshot
[image]

but on server I am getting null for these object. Here is my server side code

```
    @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/create", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public UIResponse createDS(@Validated @ModelAttribute(value = "dS") DSDto dSDto,
            BindingResult result) {
 //here dSDto.name and dSDto.description is null
}
```

Comment: try `@RequestBody` iso `@ModelAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

you have to add  the @RequestBody annotation so Spring would convert the incoming JSON to a  object from the post body .take a look  at this stack overflow post
[@RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotations in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-reponsebody-spring)